# Add multiple commands to a single command block, and alternate with +/- redstone power

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I am playing around with command blocks, and I just wanted to know if you could have multiple commands in one command block. If you can, is it possible to have one of the commands active when the command block is powered, and the other activate when the block is not powered?

Example:

- CMD 1) is powered would be   `{setblock ~ ~1 ~ 152}`
- CMD 2) is not powered would be  `{setblock ~ ~1 ~ 0}`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No. That is an unusually specific feature that would be very clearly advertised.

To do this, use two command blocks: one directly connected to the redstone and the other connected through an inverter. (If timing is critical, you may need to put a delay circuit on the 'directly' connected command block's input line, to match the delay through the inverter.)